# How to avoid URL loading the same pagename.php with slash as multiple times

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am having the weird problem while loading the page,

for example,

`http://www.example.co.uk/about_us.php/` is the right URL

But then,

WRONG URL:

`http://www.example.co.uk/about_us.php/wwewqewq`
`http://www.example.co.uk/about_us.php/about_us.php`

Still it shows the content of (`http://www.example.co.uk/about_us.php/`) with the wrong URL instead to show (URL NOT FOUND)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) set to on in your config.

You can turn it off using this line in your .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

With this directive you will start getting `/about_us.php/about_us.php` type URIs.